# Material UI or Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I need a frontend UI for my react web application and I was looking to Material UI and Reactstrap. Which one do you think is better and easier for begginers to understand? Also are there any tutorials for either them because I found both of their documentations confusing.

Comment: Which part do you find confusing ? I think both of them have excellet examples

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the documentation mostly with Material. I am confused about how to incorporate the components and than customize them as well. I don't really understand what the component  API part of the documentation is for as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about how to incorporate the components and than customize them as well

About customizing them, there is a [section](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overrides) explaining about it and they provide examples as well.

You only need to import the component you want and plug it to your React apps just like regular React component.

As for API part on Material UI, most of them consist of 3 parts (Props, CSS API, Demos) for each component. The props section provide you with all the available props for the corresponding component. For example the [Button props API](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#props), it list all the available props you can provide for the Button component

CSS API section is the section you would want to look for when you want to customize the component, it list all the available keys for you to override, in my opinion it's best to look at the corresponding component implementation before customizing it because I find it a bit tricky. The source are available for public on their [Github repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js)